# Mounting External HD inside Encrypted Folder

Tags: encryption, usb, mount

I have an external HD (USB 3.0, 1TB) that contains all of my music files.  For the past 6 months, I've had my Linux box (Xubuntu 13.04, Kernel 3.8) rigged to automatically mount this drive on login to the ~/Music folder.

The other day, I decided to encrypt my home folder.  Unfortunately, the HD no longer mounts properly in the Music folder.  It still mounts fine if I manually mount it to /media/Music or any other place outside of my home folder, but even though it claims to have mounted to ~/Music, none of my files or folders show up inside the Music folder.

Is this not doable inside an encrypted folder, even after it has been unlocked?  Or are there some extra steps I am missing?

Thanks!

Edit:  df lists the drive (/dev/sdc2) as mounted to /home//Music, but the folder is still empty.

Comment: How have you encrypted `home` folder? With ecryptfs or something other?
Also, have you removed Music from `/etc/fstab/` and mount it manually after home folde password was entered?

Answer (score 0):

Best solution to use encrypted file systems with the other ones is symbolic link. Mount HD to `/media/Music` and use symbolic link at home folder:

`ln -s /media/Music /home/USERNAME/Music`